# Disable optimized class loader in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm currently building a Laravel 5.1 system, that is being automatically deployed to several servers in several steps (local, test and production). 
Unfortunatly I have an issue with the optimized class loader. During deployment, Composer runs and through the composer.json file, the two commands `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize` runs without any problems.

My problem is that Laravel at some time during execution of a page tries to write to `/bootstrap/cache/services.json`, but this fails since the (systemwise) user that created the folder, is not the same as the user that tries to write to the file (It also doesn't make sense that it tries to optimize, since the optimiser file is already created).

- Is is possible to disable the "on-the-fly" class loader optimizer? (And if it is, what are the consequenses?)

Before any "You should just change permissions to ...", then i'd like to point out that it is currently not a viable solution. Everything is versionized, so the folder on the server is named something like `server/project/20151122192701/laravel` and I don't think our tech guys are intersted in changing permissions every time we commit to production :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize` from the `composer.json` to prevent the commands from running when committing. I also `!services.json` to `/bootstrap/cache/.gitignore` (to make it committable) and committing `services.json` with new writeable permissions (755).

This is to prevent the deploy user from deleting `services.json` and recreating it with no-write permissions...

I had some other problems with Laravel also caching views and sessions, but this was solved by caching views in the system temp folder (i know this is probably not the best solution, but it works) and using `memcached` for sessions.